# document.creatElement can't show utf8 chars

Tags: javascript, html, utf-8

I create label elem with document.crteateElement and I set text value to elem with .innerHTML but on page browser don't show utf-8 characters correct I see only '?' in black rectangle.

This my hrml charset:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-9">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-language" CONTENT="tr">
```

I use this function for convert :

```
GetChar(char) {
    return unescape(decodeURIComponent(char))
  }
```

and this is my value 
`const  target= '${this.GetChar('İ')}stikamet'`

then here is I set value to label elem

```
 var elem = document.createElement('label)
 elem.innerHTML = target
```

What is the corrent way show this characters on browser ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead of your current meta-tags

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

EDIT:

The following HTML displays your example-char fine for me:

```
<html>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <body>
        <label>İ</label>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The function unescape is the deprecated version of decodeURIComponent. This means that do the same. Do you need your GetChar function? If you do, maybe it should instead be decodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(char)).

Comment: I rewrite GetChar and return decodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(char)) but  I see same.

Comment: What if you write the following: 

const target = 'İ'